# Where can I find Lagrange’s original equilateral triangular solution for arbitrary masses?

Tags: mathematics, physics, newton, resource-recommendation, lagrange

[This answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/36143/7982) to *What kind of triangle is formed by three unequal masses in a circular restricted three body orbit?* explains that

> In the Newtonian limit, an equilateral 3-body solution exists for any combination of masses

and links to [Triangular solution to general relativistic three-body problem for general masses](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.0754) which stars with "Lagrange’s equilateral triangular solution for the three-body problem" and looks at relativistic ("post-Newtonian") effects.

In the [circular restricted three body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem#Restricted_three-body_problem) of [Lagrangian points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point) fame one body is a "test mass" with no significant effect on the other two, but apparently three massive bodies can also have a circular orbit solution where they still form an equilateral triangle, as $L_4$ and $L_5$ do in the CR3BP.

Where did Lagrange first write about the equilateral triangular solution for the three-body problem where all three bodies have non-zero mass?

Comment: This link may prove useful for you. The name of the book is "[Three Body Dynamics and Its Applications to Exoplanets](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319582252)". Link to [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=D90tDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=Lagrange%E2%80%99s+equilateral+triangular+solution+for+arbitrary+masses?&source=bl&ots=yPzfr9SK1U&sig=ACfU3U0Twe1ckt0eibviu7bu-HsUKku1Jg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIhKuai6zpAhXkQ98KHWjDATMQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Lagrange%E2%80%99s%20equilateral%20triangular%20solution%20for%20arbitrary%20masses%3F&f=false>)

Comment: It seems your title question is not exactly the same as your body question. Or maybe I'm misinterpreting that final sentence as "when ...."  ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I'm looking for the original writing, did Lagrange write it in a scientific paper, or in a letter, or in a journal? Thus "where" was it written.

Comment: Lagrange points /Wikipedia article ref.4 perhaps, it's a link to his  Oeuvres t.6 p. 229 and it is printed with a note "Prix de l'Academie royale des sciences de paris tome IX 1772" which could be checked.

Comment: @sand1 Thank you! Yes "any three masses" and I should have caught that. I see a link [here](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/cgi-bin/oetoc?id=OE_LAGRANGE__6) to page 229 in [gallica](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k229225j/f231) and I did study French 45 years ago :-) I'll dig in and give it a try. It's possible that no English translation exists.